# Is it possible to refer to the top-level "main" in an instance method?

Tags: ruby

If you extend the `main` object with a module, is it possible to refer to the new methods in another object?

```
module Mod
  def meth
    puts "top level"
  end
end

extend Mod  # --- not include

class My
  def meth
    puts "instance"
    TOP_LEVEL.meth # --- psuedo-code to explain the intention
  end
end

My.new.meth # prints "instance", then fails
```

Comment: What is `TOP_LEVEL`? Explain all constants that you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, without requiring a user-defined global var:

```
class My
  def meth
    puts "instance"
    TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver.meth
  end
end
```

The alternative `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('meth')` also works by calling `meth` directly, but for non-trivial methods, a handle to the "main" object returned via the `receiver` method is probably more convenient.

---

As an aside, [this blog post](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/) is worth reading to help understand why some things work, and others not, when dealing with Ruby top level.

Comment: As an aside, this is worth reading to help understand why some things work, and others not, when dealing with Ruby top level: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Comment: I don't think you need the `eval`. You can access it from just `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver`.